# Pass variables using Session throwing an exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I have a form for clients to fill out, so I decided to make it an digital form. I have three pages subscriber_details, Package_Selection and Bank_Details. When the user has filled in all fields in the first and clicks next the page progresses onto the next till all three has been filled, when all three is filled they direct to a final page where all their details are presented to them for one last time, so that they can make sure its correct... on my subscriber_details.aspx I have the following code to store their details into sessions

```
protected void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["FullName"] = txtFullName.Text;

    if (txtCompanyName.Text == String.Empty)
        Session["CompanyName"] = "N/A";
    else
    Session["CompanyName"] = txtCompanyName.Text;

    if (txtVAT.Text == String.Empty)
        Session["VAT"] = "N/A";
    else
    Session["VAT"] = txtVAT.Text;

    Session["ContactNumber"] = txtContactNumber.Text;
    if (txtFax.Text == String.Empty)
        Session["Fax"] = "N/A";
    else
        Session["Fax"] = txtFax.Text;

    if (txtDistrict.Text == String.Empty)
        Session["District"] = "N/A";
    else
        Session["District"] = txtDistrict.Text;

    Session["City"] = txtCity.Text;
    Session["Street"] = txtStreet.Text;
    Session["Code"] = txtPostal.Text;

    if (txtTrading.Text == String.Empty)
        Session["Trading"] = "N/A";
    else
    Session["Trading"] = txtTrading.Text;

    Session["ID"] = txtID.Text;
    Session["ContactPerson"] = txtContactPerson.Text;

    if (txtEmail.Text == String.Empty)
        Session["Email"] = "N/A";
    else
    Session["Email"] = txtEmail.Text;
}
```

then on my final.aspx I have the following code to use the sessions and replace the text in labels

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblFullName.Text = Session["FullName"].ToString();
    lblCompanyName.Text = Session["CompanyName"].ToString();
    lblVat.Text = Session["VAT"].ToString();
    lblContactNumber.Text = Session["ContactNumber"].ToString();
    lblFax.Text = Session["Fax"].ToString();
    lblDistrict.Text = Session["District"].ToString();
    lblStreet.Text = Session["Street"].ToString();
    lblCity.Text = Session["City"].ToString();
    lblCode.Text = Session["Code"].ToString();
    lblTrading.Text = Session["Trading"].ToString();
    lblID.Text = Session["ID"].ToString();
    lblContactPerson.Text = Session["ContactPerson"].ToString();
    lblMail.Text = Session["Email"].ToString();


}
```

for some reason I get an "Object reference error", is it because my final.aspx page isn't my next page, because I have to pass through my package.aspx and bank_details.aspx first?

I have required field validators on the sessions that doesn't have an if statement, so the text wont be empty

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting all of the Session variables. For example, you have not set `Session["Email"]` so the call to `lblMail.Text = Session["Email"].ToString();` will throw the exception.

You should populate all Session variables you want to use and also check they are not null before doing `.ToString()`. This should catch it more gracefully.

Comment: Set? Okay forgive me for asking, what do you mean by set? I have done exactly this in visual studio 2010 and had no problems, now I'm using 2012 and all of a sudden I get a error.

Comment: Set, as in `Session["Email"] = "person@home.com";`. In your question you are not setting it and more importantly you are not **checking it**! You should always check Session values before doing a `.ToString()` etc as you cannot guarantee it has been initialised.